# Jetty: Deploying projects in different context path under same URL but different port

Tags: apache, jetty

I have two projects that I must deploy in jetty.

First project must be under contextPath /project1 and URL for this project is: http://project1.loc:8088

Second project must be under contextPath /project2 and URL for this project is:
http://peoject2.loc:8089
How can I do this?